# Parse numbers by dot with std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse numbers separated with dots and get each number as sepate string. That is my sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        std::string data("123.321.456.654");
        std::regex reg(R"(([0-9]+)\.(\1)\.(\1)\.(\1))");
        std::smatch m;
        if (std::regex_match(data, m, reg))
        {
            std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;
            //std::cout << m[0].str() << std::endl;
            std::cout << m[1].str() << std::endl;
            std::cout << m[2].str() << std::endl;
            std::cout << m[3].str() << std::endl;
            std::cout << m[4].str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error occurred: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this sample I am using three regex:

works:

```
std::regex reg(R"((\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+))");
```

works:

```
std::regex reg(R"(([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+))");
```

do not work at all:

```
std::regex reg(R"(([0-9]+)\.(\1)\.(\1)\.(\1))");
```

My question is why last regex is not working and where is error in syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Because `\1` is a backreference, it is not a subroutine call that recurses the *pattern*. It matches the value captured with the first capturing group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Answers go in the answer section

Comment: This is not a C++ question but a regex question; please get into the habit of breaking down your problems into constituent parts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, so first group is `([0-9]+)` and this should be correct.

Comment: @SpaceRabbit: No, the first backreference is "123". Not `[0-9]+`. See my answer and the resource I linked you to.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: I do not answer duplicates.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Then don't answer it; but, if you're going to (and you did), don't do it in the comments section! Furthermore, if you think that this is a duplicate, use your rep to cast a duplicate vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in your syntax; it is in your logic.

Backreferences do not repeat a pattern; [they match previously-matched text](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

So, your pattern would match `123.123.123.123`.